# VS 2010 code changes gives error LNK2001 on 'Build Solution', must perform 'Rebuild Solution'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, solution, rebuild, linker-errors

Converting my project to *Visual Studio 2010*, I am facing a bothering problem.

I have a solution with 9 projects. Eight of the nine projects produce 'Static Library (.lib)' as output, and some of them depends on the other among these eight. The other project uses some of these libs and produce a 'Dynamic Library (.dll), which is the final output of the project and used by sample applications.

Now when I made some code change in **ANY** project and give 'Build Solution', then I get linking error **LNK2001**. But if I give 'Rebuild Solution', then it successfully compiles the solution and I get the effect of the change on code. But as it is a bit large project, giving 'Rebuild' on every code change is time consuming and verrry much bothering during development.

FYI, it works perfectly while I was using *Visual Studio 2005*.

Do anyone know what project settings I must change so that I may get the effect of my changed code only by giving '**Build** Solution', which only compiles the changed code and creates the final DLL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some painful hours I have solved the issue :).

According to the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/024awkd1), I have gone to **Property Page>Linkers>General** and changed the property of 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' to **True** of the project that produce the final dll. And that ends all my pain and now a 'Build Solution' simply builds the changes and creates the dynamic library accordingly.